# JAXB facilities in unmarshaling

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jaxb, unmarshalling

Hello guys how can i unmarshall list of objects in XML. My XML will be like this

```
<messageContainer class="class1">
    <a>         
        <b />
    </a>
    <MessageB />
</messageContainer>
<messageContainer class="class2">
    <a>         
        <b />
    </a>
    <MessageB />
</messageContainer>
```

And i want to get list of object in the end.

Comment: This looks like a strange approach to me. Do you have to be able to marshal literally any class there is? Or is it just a couple of classes that you have in your app? Is the XML format just an idea of yours or a requirement given by your superiors/clients? Using JAXB annotations in your classes should do the trick. Composition is not a problem as long as the annotations are provided for all classes used for your fields.

Comment: I have some classes and i do not know what will be in this XML. And yes i should parse such XML.

Comment: can You give us your whole XML file?

Answer (score 0):

Any Valid XML file can contain only one XML Root Element.
 I assume that u have the above list as a child of an RootElement(say ).

Then your annotated RootElement class should look like this.

> ```
> @XmlRootElement(name = "RootElement")
> public class RootElement{
>           @XmlElement(name = "messageContainer", required = true)
>           private List<messageContainer> containerList;
>   }
> ```

Where MessageContainer is a class by itself.

**Note :** The more simpler way to generate these binding class is, write XSD(or generate using online tools) for your XML and compile those XSD with XJC compiler.